# How to convert two arrays of same length into one array of objects in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach, javascript-objects

I have two arrays that look like this:

```
array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
array2 = [a, b, c, d, e];
```

Using JavaScript, I want to convert two arrays of same length into array of objects that would look like this:

```
newArrayofObjects = [ {key1: 1, key2: a}, {key1: 2, key2: b}, {key1: 3, key2: c},  {key1: 4, key2: d}, {key1: 5, key2: e}]
```

Comment: this seems really straightforward - have you actually tried solving this yourself?  i'm sure someone will give you an answer but imo you will do better to spend some time trying to come up with a solution on your own.

Comment: hint: get length, iterate using a `for` loop

Comment: I've removed the "json" tag from your question because there's no JSON involved here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Array.map comes in handy a lot.

```
var newArray = array1.map(function(e,i){return{key1:e,key2:array2[i]}});
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], array2 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], newArrayofObjects = [];
for(var key = 0; key < array1.length; key++) {
    newArrayofObjects.push({key1 : array1[key], key2 : array2[key]});
}
```